# Django Rest Framework Not Null Constraint

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When i try to create a new by post by posting the following Json:

```
{
"title": "This is serialzer title",
"content": "This is serialzer content",
}
```

I get the following error:

```
NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_post.views
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now

# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField()
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        # return self.title + ' by ' + self.author
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author.username


class BlogComment(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    comment = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment[0:13] + "..." + " by " + self.user.username
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def api_create_blog_view(request):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
    blog_post = Post(author=user)
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = PostSerializer(blog_post, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

serializer.py

```
from blog.models import Post
from rest_framework import serializers

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

I don't know how to solve this please help me to solve this error.DB has already been cleared. Locations have been created by using the admin interface. I know that the issue is something trivial, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: You need to set the `views` value.

Comment: as per your model definition, `views` field should contain a valid *integer* upon `Post` creation, But, you are not accepting the value for `views` from API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value for the `views`. You can do so by specifying a `default` value:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Post(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    timeStamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.author.username
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: According to the [*PEP-8 Style Guide*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the classes should be written in `PerlCase`, and the fields in `snake_case`.